# Sending sms and receiving delivery report in J2me

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am developing a project where I need to send an sms to the contact and if the contact doesn't receives the sms I have to send him another or choose another contact. So, for notifying my midlet of successful sms delivery i'll need to receive and read the sms delivery report.

**How to read delivery report using j2me? Or Is there any other way to achieve this?**

Comment: There's no way to check if the user has received the message. You send the message to the carrier network, and that's all.

Comment: Ya! but I also came across that we can read sms sent to the specific port. Do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: You can send sms to a specific port. But an app should be running in the recipient device listening in the same port. If you are going to develop a receiver app, then you could just include a text "header" in every SMS body, and code this listener app identifying your sms by the header, then sending a response ACK SMS back.

Comment: Thank you for reply. There is something more I would like to ask you. I am also having problem regarding calling to the contact but every time I initiate a call device asks for permission from user. I just need to initiate call straight away without user's interaction. I also have set call control option to always allow on nokia E72 device for that midlet but was not helpful. It asks yes or no and on agree it asks whether to initiate a voice or a video call. Can you help me solve this.

Comment: Annoying permissions prompts is one of the things that killed the JavaME platform. Everytime you access a "sensitive" API, such as files, connections, etc; a prompt will be shown. Only a signed app can avoid this pain. And to sign it you need to purchase a cert, which is not cheap at all. Have a look at [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/index-156128.html) and [this post](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Java_Security_Domains).

Comment: Yes I do have a signed my application. What kind of certificate will I need to remove all prompts completely? Even while attempt make a phone call.

Comment: Main ones are from [Thawte](https://www.thawte.com/code-signing/content-signing-certificates/sun-java/index.html) and [Verisign (now Symantec)](https://www.symantec.com/verisign/code-signing/java). I don't know of any other way, but you might want to research this a bit before spending 300 bucks for a year :)

Answer (score 1):

If you put your application on the Nokia store it will be automatically signed by Nokia to the 3rd party trusted domain, so the prompts will be less. Also i think if you implement SATSA JSR http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_and_Trust_Services_API_for_J2ME you can talk to the Sim card and get relevant information maybe on delivery of SMS also, but you need the app to be signed to the operator domain for permission. On the other hand, if you have an SMPP connection to a server you can send SMS to users with a port number and also view the message status there.